# How to point Apache Shiro to multiple dynamically generated LDAP servers?

Tags: tomcat, ldap, shiro

I lookup LDAP servers using this method . The list contains about 30 LDAP servers. In my Tomcat application I need to authorize users . I could't find any documentation for how to do this with Shiro. I know  how to point to one `LDAP`. But how can I point to multiple `LDAP` servers? Any of these `LDAP` servers could be down at any time. Most of them are up though usually.  Also how do I refresh the `LDAP` list periodically? I don't have any control over LDAP. So I need to point Shiro to what the below method returns

```
    public List<String> getLdapServers (final String dnsServQuery)
    {
        final List<String> serverList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            final DirContext dnsContext = new InitialDirContext(env);
            final String dnsQueryType[] = { "SRV" };

           . . . blah blah 

        return serverList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this.
1.) you could just generate a `shiro.ini` before Shiro is loaded (simple, but not exactly a robust solution)
2.) You could create a new realm (extending the LDAP realm) and handle your initialization that way.
3.) Implement an [LdapContextFactory](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.3.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/realm/ldap/JndiLdapContextFactory.html) and manage the connection this way.

I'd recommend #3